# Wait minimum time before continuing

Tags: javascript

I have this function that waits for is_user_dict to return true, then uploads some profile data to a database and moves on with the program. While that's happening I have an animation I would like to play for at least 2 seconds if the rest of the function takes less than that much time to complete.

Previously I handled this using setTimeout, but that prevents the function from actually doing anything during that waiting period, slowing the program down needlessly. What's the best way for me to make sure showLogoAnimation runs for at least 2 seconds, but not longer than needed?

I know I could measure the time between start_time and the time the function is ready and use a while loop until that much time had passed, but as is I know my code is already sloppy and that there's probably a better way to do what I'm doing?

```
async function handleTestStart() {
    traceFunction()
    character.style.backgroundImage = "url(character.png)"
    left_button.style.visibility = 'visible'
    right_button.style.visibility = 'visible'
    showLogoAnimation()
    let start_time = new Date().getTime()
    while (!is_user_dict) {
        let end_time = new Date().getTime()
        let time = end_time - start_time
        if (time > 10000) {
            timeoutError()
        }
    }
    let is_profile_ready = createProfile()
    let start_time2 = new Date().getTime()
    is_profile_ready.then((result) => {
        let end_time2 = new Date().getTime()
        let time2 = end_time2 - start_time2
        if (time2 > 10000) {
            timeoutError()
        }
        hideLogoAnimation()
        condition_category_array.forEach(function (condition_category) {
            user_dict['more_info'].push(condition_category)
        })
        category = user_dict['more_info'][0]
        backup_user_dict = deepCopyObject(user_dict)
        nextQuestion()
    })
}
```

Comment: You might want to take a visit to [the User Experience Stack Exchange](https://ux.stackexchange.com/) to verify whether or not it is advisable to force the user to wait unnecessarily while you show a loading animation... Not saying it is definitely incorrect, but it raises a flag for me.

Comment: It's really just that I like my loading animation, but it looks strange when it appears for half a second. This is an animation that only loads one time, so it won't impede the user experience. I just want the animation to look aesthetically pleasing because I specifically timed it to loop every two seconds. I do appreciate the link though and I will keep that in mind in the future.

Comment: Depending on how quickly the user goes through the prompts, the function can already be loaded or may take half a second to a second. Since I can't anticipate how long it will take to be ready, I just wanted to establish a consistent minimum animation time for aesthetic reasons.

Comment: I think [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) would help here: `Promise.all([createProfile(), makeTimer()]).then(([profile, nothing]) => { /* ?? */}`.  It will proceed when both your `createProfile`  Promise and your timer one have completed.  However I agree with the comment that this is usually a bad UX choice.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I'll consider whether or not it's a bad idea for me to do this at all before I continue.